# Passing pointer to dynamically allocated array by copy to function has unexpected result

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, dynamic

I was just messing around with passing pointers to functions to wrap my head around how it works and I came across some behavior that was unexpected. I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct t
{
    string x;
    string y;
};

void foo(t*);

int main()
{

    t* ts = new t[2];
    ts[0].x = "t1.x";
    ts[0].y = "t1.y";
    ts[1].x = "t2.x";
    ts[1].y = "t2.y";

    foo(ts); 

    cout << ts[0].x << endl;

}

void foo(t* s)
{
    delete[] s;
    s = new t[2];
    s[0].x = "FOO.X";
    s[1].y = "FOO.Y";
}
```

The output here, interestingly enough, is `"FOO.X"`. I expected that since inside of `foo`, `s` is a copy of the pointer `ts` that when I `delete[] s` I effectively `delete[] ts` as they both point to the same address. Then `s = new t[2];` should have no effect on `ts`. After `foo` returns, I should no longer have access to `s` or the array it points to and `ts` should point to who knows where. Am I missing somehthing?

Note: This is just a test project that I made where I constantly write and erase blocks of code to test different concepts. All the includes and using namespace std is for ease of use, and it is NOT code that I am writing for any sort of practical use, purely educational. Also, I am using MS VS 2013.

Comment: You seem to already know you obliterate the data pointed to by `ts` in `main()` (and create a memory leak in the process, btw). So is your question why invoking *undefined behavior* by still trying to use that address seems to work?

Comment: We really need a canonical dupe for "why didn't undefined behavior do what I expected".

Comment: you should `delete [] ts;`

Comment: @user2357112 if only it were that simple. Trying to define undefinable is a tough draw. There are a few out there that are pretty good, though.

Comment: [Very near duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope), with an answer applicable to this question despite the differences.

Comment: @user2357112 I wasn't expecting it to do anything, I was expecting it not to do what it did, leading me to believe that there may be something I didn't learn yet that caused this. Thank you for the link to the other question, it did come close to answering mine. Anyway you guys can all chill out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your foo() like this and see the result:

```
void foo(t* s)
{
  delete[] s;

  // Additional memory allocation
  t* u = new t[2];

  s = new t[2];
  s[0].x = "FOO.X";
  s[1].y = "FOO.Y";
}
```

By adding another memory allocation, I moved `s` to another location in the memory, which is not anymore overlapping with `ts`. Otherwise, `s` was simply allocated at the same location where `ts` previously resided.

As pointed out in the comments, you are observing an *undefined behavior*, which you should by no means rely on. The example above illustrates that pretty well.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and not just an annoying comment about predicting undefined behavior.